# SageMaker Neo PyTorch 1.0.0

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I've updated the torch version in my SageMaker `pytorch_36` kernel to torch version 1.0.0. I then tried running the example notebook `pytorch_torchvision_neo.ipynb`, also changing the `framework_version` to 1.0.0. Neo compilation then fails.

Any idea why it isn't working with 1.0.0? The console error message actually tells me to make sure I'm using 1.0.0, but the example notebook seems to only work with 0.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Sagemaker notebook has pytorch-1.1.0 pre-installed.
But Model Compilation service expects model saved by `pytorch-0.4.0` or `pytorch-1.0.1`

Solution to the issue:

```
# 1. do not install `pytorch-cpu` and `torchvision-cpu`.

# 2. Downgrade pytorch version to 1.0.1
!conda install -y pytorch=1.0.1 -c pytorch 

# 3. import pytorch and check that version is 1.0.1 (but not 1.1.0)
import torch 
torch.__version__
```

Continue to run notebook steps: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker_neo_compilation_jobs/pytorch_torchvision/pytorch_torchvision_neo.ipynb